# Laravel unique validation with Route parameter

Tags: validation, laravel, unique, getter

I'm a newbie in PHP, so now i need to validate model with static variable.

This is what i have

```
class Setting extends Model {

    protected $table = 'settings';

    public static $rules = [
        'skey' => 'required|unique:table,id,' . Route::input('settings')
    ];
}
```

It throws following error : **syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ']'**

Ok, I understand that can not used in declaring variable.

Now, this is my question:

- How can I done this with Illuminate\Http\Request, I dont want to create a new SettingRequest that can use easier.
- I also dont want use in store or update method in controller. I want to use this way in both 2 method create/update.
- In PHP, anyway to create setter or getter as C#.

Comment: If you print `Route::get('settings')` what you're getting ?

Comment: It return route parameter. Ex: /settings/5 => 5

Comment: I doubt that `Route::get('settings')` gives you "5"... Try `Request::input('settings')` instead.

Comment: I tried before. Same result.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it like this as Luis said.

I assumed that you're using L5. Better practise is using a `Request` class.

```
<?php 
    namespace App\Http\Requests;

    class SettingRequest extends Request
    {
        /**
         * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
         *
         * @return bool
         */
        public function authorize()
        {
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
         *
         * @return array
         */
        public function rules()
        {
            return [
                'skey' => 'required|unique:table,id,' .$this->input('settings')
            ];
        }
    }
```

after that you can use the `SettingRequest` class as a method parameter in your controller like this:

```
public function update(SettingRequest $request) {}
public function create(SettingRequest $request) {}
```

Comment: Hi I said in above post, assume if I dont want it, anyway to make getter or setter in php without create new Request class or use as a function ( getRules()) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in that context. Try to do it inside a method:

```
public static function getRules()
{
    return  [
            'skey' => 'required|unique:table,id,' . Route::input('settings')
    ];
}
```